# Smartcard Driver (KMDF with SCardLib) Issues

Tags: windows, device-driver, drivers, smartcard, kmdf

I'm developing Smartcard Driver using **KMDF** and **SCardlib**, I used the WDK Smarcard Sample as reference, I think I implemented all of the callbacks correctly except for `CardPower` and `CardTracking`. (My reader and card don't now support for now RESET commands and insertion of new card)

When I try to run test application that invoke `SCardListReaders()` I'm getting `SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE`. I used INF like the one of the sample with changes and I Create a Device Interface with *SmartCardReaderGuid* and I set the device type to `FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD`.

I don't know what else can I do, how can I debug this? any ideas?

P.S. Why the Header file for SCarLlib are no in the inc of WDK but in the sample directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to send a good ATR buffer according to the RDF_POWER Callback spec.
and also I had to implemented the RDF_CAR_TRACKING according to the sample.